# Are questions about making cooking equipment on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Related to this question:

[Home-made gas grill burners?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/95220/home-made-gas-grill-burners)

Are questions about how to make equipment (either components, as in this case, or hypothetically a more complete object like a chef's knife or oven) topical for Seasoned Advice?

Answer (score 1):

According to the help center, questions about cooking equipment are allowed.  There are certainly people who have knowledge of cooking related issues, and the issues encountered when attempting to build and "hack" kitchen equipment.  Dave Arnold (while I doubt he is on this board) comes to mind, as someone who has sort of made a career out of solving these kinds of problems.

It appears we have accepted questions like this.  See [this one about hacking an oven](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/31907/can-i-do-anything-to-make-my-gas-oven-better).

[This question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33991/what-should-i-use-to-build-a-parrilla) is much more simple, but it is about building a sort of grill.

The part about the example question that bothers me is the question about safety...can I do this and not die...

It's one thing to be able to communicate how a gas grill burner works.  It's another to suggest that creating your own is completely safe.  Of course similar issues arise when we address food safety.

On the other hand, there is a DIY stack exchange.  I am sure there is overlap between other stack exchange sites.  Can we offer what we know from a cooking equipment perspective, and then recommend a visit to another location (such as the DIY stack exchange) if someone actually wants to build something, or does that get too messy?